# Dart initializer in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

It looks easy, but not working. I have model in Dart like this:

```dart
class FormTab {
  String caption;
  FormTab(dynamic m) { // where m will be Map
    this.caption = m['caption'] ?? "No caption";
  }
}
```

But still I have error message: `Non-nullable instance field 'caption' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.`
What is wrong? I set value `caption`, but still I have error. I tried `caption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a constructor in Dart is not part of the initializers. You need to put that into the initializer list:

```
class FormTab {
  String caption;
  FormTab(dynamic m) : caption = m['caption'] ?? "No caption";
}
```

Please note that if you *know* it's going to be a map, it might be better to make it a map. The earlier you switch from `dynamic` to actual types, the easier it is to catch errors.

Comment: thank You! I just start write this class, and now I must add new, more advanced fields, so probably I must do it using `late` word, but thank You, Your response is very important for me